# Magento new host - 403 Forbidden - Server unable to read htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento

I have moved to a new host and setup everything, but when I try to access the site, I get the following `403 Forbidden` error

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /webfiles on this server. Server
>   unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a `404 Not Found` error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any ideas on the problem?

Comment: htaccess file permission? file and dir/s permission/s owner? Everything is correct?

Answer (score 5):

very easy just go to your main directori example 
home/example 
go to the directory public html and then go to you setting by the fault the system goes to 754 you will have to change to 755  the last 5 is go ing to allow  to get to the site. cheers

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out right after I posted. it was the file permission problem in the main root