# Django site served on Apache server doesn't work, logs have no error

Tags: django, apache, firewall

I've a Django website located at `/home/rohit/django-site/infer`, in a server. `apache2` and `wsgi` are already installed and working correctly. To see that:

```
$ systemctl status apache2.service 
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-05-03 19:12:34 IST; 31min ago
  Process: 9354 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9364 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9368 (apache2)
    Tasks: 24 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─9368 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─9370 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─9371 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─9372 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─9373 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─9374 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─9375 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Here is the content of `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Fri May 03 17:04:03.885793 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24349] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 03 17:04:03.885868 2019] [core:notice] [pid 24349] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri May 03 19:12:34.361607 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24349] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri May 03 19:12:34.480584 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9368] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 03 19:12:34.480660 2019] [core:notice] [pid 9368] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Looking at which, I understand that everything is okay.

The `/var/log/apache2/access.log` is empty though, which means that all the requests made by me for the site didn't even reach the server. That seems like a firewall issue.

**Firewall**

The firewall has specifically allowed port `8000` to be accessed from outside world. That means that even port `80` (`http`) isn't allowed to be accessed from the outside world.

To test that, I ran `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` from the server, and successfully accessed the site from my laptop, by visiting `<ip-of-server>:8000`. That means that port `8000` is accessible from outside.

Now, to make sure that apache serves on this port, I edited the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`, which now looked like:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/rohit/django-site/infer/static
        <Directory /home/rohit/django-site/infer/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/rohit/django-site/infer/infer>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess infer python-path=/home/rohit/django-site/infer python-home=/home/rohit/django-site/inferenv
        WSGIProcessGroup infer
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rohit/django-site/infer/infer/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

---

So, after doing all this, when I put the address `<ip-of-server>:8000` on my browser, I get an "unable to connect" error. Plus, the empty `access.log` means that the request never reached the server. But port `8000` is open, so the firewall shouldn't be the problem. So, is there anything that might be causing the problem?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You probably need a `Listen 8000` outside the VirtualHost block.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you explain? I might not know the format to write that down.

Comment: Literally, put that at the start of the file.

Comment: Okay, added `Listen 8000` to the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file, and now I get a 403 forbidden error saying: `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

Comment: I think you need to add an Allow/Deny for your root directory `/home/rohit/django-site/infer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman), I added `Listen 8000` to the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

I also needed to allow access to my project's home directory. So I added the following to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, as suggested by [MaximeK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5073377/maximek)

```
<Directory /home/rohit/django-site/infer>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then I changed the permissions for `/home/rohit/django-site/infer`, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42396350/5345646) answer, by:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 <site_top_folder>
```