# Apache + Django + wsgi.py. Site can't be reached

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to setup Apache2 on EC2 machine with Django server. mainly for Daemon process. However i am unable to access my website through Apache. I tried listing to different ports like 80, 443, 8000 but no luck.

I am a**ble to access** my website with

```
django_project$ python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 or 

django_project$ python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:443
```

**Here is my  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        Alias /static /home/ubuntu/project/django_project/django_project/static
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/project/django_project/django_project/static>
                 Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/project/django_project/django_project/>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                         Require all granted
                </Files>
         </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess django_project python-path=/home/ubuntu/project/django_project  python-home=/home/ubuntu/env_folder/my_env3.6 user=ubuntu
        WSGIProcessGroup django_project
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/project/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache Status:**

```
/django_project$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-01-04 01:14:15 UTC; 2min 22s ago
  Process: 4706 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4712 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4742 (apache2)
    Tasks: 73 (limit: 4633)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─4742 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─4745 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─4746 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─4747 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Jan 04 01:14:15 ip-X.X.XX.XX systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 04 01:14:15 ip-X.X.XX.XX apachectl[4712]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using X.X.XX.XX. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Jan 04 01:14:15 ip-X.X.XX.XX systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

**/var/log/apache2/error.log**

```
[Sat Jan 04 01:14:15.784544 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4742:tid 140504902548416] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jan 04 01:14:15.785043 2020] [core:notice] [pid 4742:tid 140504902548416] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
~
```

I followed these two links to debug but no luck :

1. [how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04)
2. [django-site-served-on-apache-server-doesnt-work-logs-have-no-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55971841/django-site-served-on-apache-server-doesnt-work-logs-have-no-error)

In #2, He faced same challenge but he was able to resolve it. for me no luck.

Any help is much appreciated !

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for django_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Comment: Can you once share the code in your settings.py?

Comment: added settings.py.

Comment: @rshrc do you see anything wrong  in my config ?

Comment: Did you solve it?