# Laravel file upload returns forbidden 403, file permission is 700 not 755

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I'm using Laravel and uploading files to a folder using this code:

```
$request->file('file')[$key]->storeAs('public/' . $model[0] . '/' . $data['id'], $name);
```

I have already run this command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

On localhost everything is working, but when I upload it to cPanel I get this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource. 
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I checked the uploaded file had permission `700`, and not `755` like the folder `$model[0]`.

How can I fix this problem?

My `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The error message reads `Server unable to read htaccess file` - so which permissions does the htaccess file have? 700? Probably needs 755 as well, not just the directory.

Comment: the permission of the .htaccess file is 644 is inside public folder

Comment: Then you might try 755. I googled *htaccess typical chmod permissions* and found answers like this: [server unable to read htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365981/server-unable-to-read-htaccess-file-denying-access-to-be-safe)

Comment: @PeterKrebs what are you talking about? It's a text configuration file, why would it need executable permissions?

Comment: @miken32 The file was already 644 and didn't work. Sometimes it needs a little chmod ointment in my experience, if just for confirming whether more permissions work or not. Then also checking directory permissions and so on. You can't find the problem without changing anything.

Comment: Again, it's a world-readable text configuration file. Why would it need executable permissions?

Comment: @softya I think you have a permissions problem with a directory somewhere, that is causing most (if not all) your issues. And the focus on the `.htaccess` file is a red herring. **See my updated answer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing could be due to incorrect file permissions for the storage folder. Here are some steps to fix the problem:

1. SSH into your cPanel server.
2. Change the permission of the storage folder to 755:

   ```
   chmod -R 755 storage/
   ```

This command will change the permission of the storage folder and all its contents to 755, which should give the web server permission to read and write to the folder.

3. Check the ownership of the storage folder. Ensure that the owner of the folder is the same as the user running the web server (typically www-data on Apache):

   ```
    ls -l
   ```

This command will list the files and folders in the current directory along with their ownership and permission details. Make sure that the owner of the storage folder is the same as the user running the web server.

4. If the ownership is incorrect, you can change it using the following command:

   ```
     chown -R www-data:www-data storage/
   ```

This command will change the ownership of the storage folder and all its contents to the www-data user and group, which is typically used by Apache.

5. Finally, make sure that the file upload path is correct. Check that the $model[0] and $data['id'] variables have the correct values and that the public directory is at the root of the web server.
   After making these changes, try uploading a file again and see if the issue is resolved.

After making these changes, try uploading a file again and see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: You probably should only apply 755 to directories and 644 to files.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pointed out, the reported errors are actually multiple separate issues. I'll address them in order.

First, in your Apache configuration file, the `User` and `Group` specify what user/group to run the Apache process. I'll just refer to this setting as *User* below.

> Forbidden
> You don't have permission to access this resource.

This means the Apache server can not read the index file. There are a number of possibilities, so I'll run each down:

- Your *User* doesn't have permission to the `index.php` or `index.html` in that directory. Change it's permissions to 644.
- Your *User* doesn't have execute permission to the parent directories. Make sure to grant `+x`. Numerically, that means all the directories back to `/` must end in 1, 3, 5, or 7 in the whole path to your Apache `<Directory /path/to/directory>` setting.

> Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe.

This means your `.htaccess` is not readable by your *User*. It is a good idea to have the `.htaccess` owned by `root` and the group set to your *Group* setting. Then make sure it has 644 permissions.

> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

This means the Apache *User* doesn't have permission to read the file or URL pointed to in your `ErrorDocument` setting.

---

Additionaly, you should also make sure your storage directory from Laravel is writable by the Apache `User` or `Group`.

Answer (score -2):

**.htacces File: Chmod (to 755) is one option.**

Another is to correct the owner or group with Chown to that of the Webserver.
in standard setups mostly called "www-data"
Shell: chown www-data .htaccess (Owner)
or Shell: chown root.www-data .htaccess (Group)
or both Shell: chown www-data.www-data .htaccess (Owner&Group)

**But your Error may be related to File permissions of the uploaded file**

Maybe you have to define and apply the visibility to the uplaoded files too.
Hace a look into:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#file-visibility