# Apache2 / PHP-FPM / FPM pool / Why am I having a forbidden access (403)?

Tags: php, apache, fpm

it seems I made something wrong or I didn't understand …
Fist of all, explanations about what I want to do :
I would like to have differents PHP-FPM sockets with differents users for differents sites.

I need this, because the devs in my team write code on their own computer but the source code is sent via SFTP on a developpment server. And we are not able to connect on the server with the www-data account (for obvious security resons).

I use Apache2 with PHP-FPM without any problem with default conf, but now I face a problem.
When I configure my pool for my user, if the directory is only readable for my user account I have a 403 HTTP error.

There are my confs (the user is hthomas) :
User infos :

```bash
[root:/var/www/html/dev/hippolyte]#groups hthomas
hthomas : www-data sudo hthomas
[root:/var/www/html/dev]#ls -lah
total 12K
drwxrwxr-- 3 www-data www-data 4,0K 15 juin  15:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4,0K 15 juin  16:19 ..
drwxrwxr-- 5 hthomas  www-data 4,0K 30 juin  14:28 hippolyte
```

FPM-pool :

```bash
[root:/var/www/html/dev]#cat /etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/fpm-hthomas.conf
[hthomas]

user = hthomas
group = hthomas

listen = /run/php/php8.2-fpm.hthomas.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

Apache conf :

```bash
[root:/var/www/html/dev]#cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/hippolyte.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hippolyte-dev.***.fr

    Redirect permanent / https://hippolyte-dev.***.fr/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite **********************************************
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/all.***.fr.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/all.***.fr.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/chains/all.***.fr_bundle.crt
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive \
        ssl-unclean-shutdown

    ServerName hippolyte-dev.***.fr
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/hippolyte

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.hthomas.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "/var/www/html/dev/hippolyte">
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/hippolyte-dev_error-ssl.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/hippolyte-dev_access-ssl.log combined


        Alias /xlone "/var/www/html/dev/hippolyte/xlone/app/public"
        <Directory "/var/www/html/dev/hippolyte/xlone/app/public">
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

With this conf, the access is ok :
[image]

But if I change the group of my directory :

```bash
[root:/var/www/html/dev]#chown -R hthomas:hthomas hippolyte/
[root:/var/www/html/dev]#ls -lah
total 12K
drwxrwxr-- 3 www-data www-data 4,0K 15 juin  15:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4,0K 15 juin  16:19 ..
drwxrwxr-- 5 hthomas  hthomas  4,0K 30 juin  14:28 hippolyte
```

And after a server restart :

```bash
[root:/var/www/html/dev]#service apache2 restart
```

[image]

So, the question is : if I made something wrong, what was it ? Or if it's normal, please explain it to me :)

Comment: The last screenshot shows “Server unable to read htaccess file”. Does this answer your question? [Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365981/server-unable-to-read-htaccess-file-denying-access-to-be-safe)

Comment: @A.L : With the exact same apache and fpm configuration when the owner group of the directory is www-data it's working. But in the FPM socket configuration the connection user and group are hthomas. So, basiccaly, I think the owner of the directory should be capable to get data from it. But no, so my question is am I misconfugered something ? And no, you're link does not answer my question because I can make it work but not in the way I want :)

Comment: @BrunoDesprez: The sockets user/group is irrelevant for Apache when accessing the .htaccess file. _Before_ it will  even touch the socket, it is looking for the .htaccess file in the file-system. As you have removed access to it, you get what you asked for ;) Perhaps you now want to ask about how to tell Apache to not process [.htaccess files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html#htaccess)?