# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server. Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, httpforbiddenhandler

Right now I'm getting this message in a single site of my whole reseller account: Forbidden

> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Server unable to
>   read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

It happened all of a sudden. I tried renaming the root htaccess to anything else, and the error is still there, I even tried setting up 744 permissions to the file, still the same thing. Currently the file is using the default files permissions, 644.
The error is ocuring at: http://lucrebem.com.br

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890751/magento-new-host-403-forbidden-server-unable-to-read-htaccess-file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add a `<Directory` block to your apache config

```
<Directory "/path/to/source/file/directory/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This grants the required permission

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88337/discussion-between-marshallofsound-and-user3692451).

Answer (score 14):

So the problem was that the public_html folder changed permissions to 744, but I never changed it. I solved it changed the permissions to 750.
But how do I see the logs???
Because I never did a change on that folder, I'm afraid it might have been an attack.

Answer (score 1):

Open your cPanel -> Go to 'addon domain' -> then go to 'modify addon domain' section -> then click on edit 'document root' -> click on chenge icon -> then just click on 'Change' button

That's all.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue in Wordpress website. I have changed file permission in "cpanel/public_html" folder. Problem solved for me. So please try it.